# Unable to open Port 8080 for Varnish to access Nginx

Tags: nginx, varnish

I am setting up Varnish and Hitch to serve incomming HTTP and HTTPS requests for my Drupal Website. The Drupal website runs on Nginx on a Digital Ocean VPS and was listening on port 80 and 443. I have changed all sever blocks to listen on port 8080. I have configured Varnish to listen on 80 on the same machine. I created a shell script to set up the iptables. The script contains the following lines

```
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9999 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4949 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ipchains -A input -p icmp --icmp-type timestamp-request -j DROP ipchains -A output -p icmp --icmp-type timestamp-reply -j DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -L -n
iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/sysconfig/iptables
service iptables restart
```

When I list the iptables rules after executing the above script this is the output

```
sridhar@SastraTechnologies:~$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for sridhar: 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9999
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:munin
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The http-alt is the port 8080 as that is the last rule in my iptables shell script. However when I try a telnet I get a "Connection refused" error

```
sridhar@SastraTechnologies:~$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Tried checking if varnish is able to connect to Nginx by using curl from my laptop to fetch the headers and this is the output (ip addressed obfuscated for obvious reasons)

```
sridhar@sridhar-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ curl -I 139.99.99.99 
HTTP/1.1 503 Backend fetch failed
Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2021 08:57:53 GMT
Server: Varnish
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Retry-After: 5
X-Varnish: 4271
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Connection: keep-alive
```

However if i check the port status using netstat I see that Nginx is listening on the port 8080

```
sridhar@SastraTechnologies:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2246/varnishd   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8999          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1543/perl       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      541/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 139.99.99.99:3306       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1472/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9050/sshd       
tcp        0      0 139.99.99.99:8080       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4071/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2246/varnishd   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4071/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::9999                 :::*                    LISTEN      9050/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2246/varnishd   
tcp6       0      0 :::4949                 :::*                    LISTEN      7923/perl
```

But its listening to port 80 on only the public IP instead of all the IP's, its not the same for all the other ports. Is there anything that I am missing? How do I get port 8080 to be accessible to Varnish?

**EDIT**

### System Unit File contents

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/reload-vcl
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Back end definition for Varnish

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

Only changed the backend default configuration for now

### Nginx Configuration

```
server {
        listen mydomain.co.in:8080;
        server_name mydomain.co.in www.mydomain.co.in;
    root /home/sridhar/public_html/newanybank/public; ## <-- Your only path reference.

    keepalive_timeout 70;
    access_log /home/sridhar/public_html/newanybank/log/access.log;
    error_log /home/sridhar/public_html/newanybank/log/error.log;

    # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg  ^ modue# by serving Gzip versions of the files.
    gzip_static on;

    index index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }


    # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
            allow 192.168.0.0/16;
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {

      return 403;
    }

    # No no for private
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
            return 403;
    }

    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
            return 403;
    }

    location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
            expires max;
    }

    location @rewrite {
            # You have 2 options here
            # For D7 and above:
            # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
            rewrite ^ /index.php;
            # For Drupal 6 and bwlow:
            # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
            # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
            #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/phpfpm.sock;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # This is for D6
    #location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
    # This is for D7 and D8
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires 365d;
            log_not_found off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    }

    location ~* \.(pdf|css|html|js|swf)$ {
            expires 7d;
            log_not_found off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the system unit file for Varnish, the backend definition in your VCL file, and the virtual host file for Nginx. I'd like to see how things are configured.

Comment: I have just included the information that you mentioned in your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `listen mydomain.co.in:8080;` directive in your Nginx config is probably the issue.

Nginx will only listen on the network interface for the IP that is resolved by the domain. I'm well aware that the domain is redacted for the sake of privacy. But you probably know what I mean.

This is also reflected by the `139.99.99.99:8080` local address in your `netstat` output.

The `localhost` address doesn't resolve to that IP address, and uses the loopback interface. So that's probably why it won't work.

Please change your Nginx listen address as follows:

```
listen 8080;
```

This will bind the Nginx process to all available network interfaces on that server, including `localhost`.

Comment: Let me try. Will post the results. There are other server blocks on nginx. The server_name directive should handle it provided nginx receives the domain name from Varnish.

Comment: You were spot on. It worked. Nginx was indeed binding to the public ip when the listen directive had domainname:8080. Having just the listen 8080 lets nginx bind on localhost 8080. telnet localhost 8080 now works and varnish is now able to connect to the backend nginx server.